# Excel Macro to draw thread comments from website into cells

Tags: excel, reddit, vba

I am trying to store Reddit thread comments in an excel spreadsheet, however I have had trouble trying to figure out how to do this. I do not have much experience with using macros to get data from webpages, so I have been finding it hard to figure out how exactly to draw out each comment from a specified Reddit thread and place it in a cell, and whether or not it is possible to do.

This is what I have so far:

```
Sub getRedditData()

Dim x As Long, y As Long
Dim htm As Object

Set htm = CreateObject("htmlFile")

With CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")
    .Open "GET", "https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/4p7qsx/what_are_the_most_common_modern_day_scams/", False
    .send
    htm.body.innerhtml = .responsetext
End With

With htm.getelementbyid("comments")
    Set cellrangex = .Rows(x).Cells.Length - 1
    Set cellrangey = .Rows(x).Cells.Length - 1
    Set cellrange1 = Sheets(1).Cells(x + 1, y + 1).Value
    Set cellrange2 = .Rows(x).Cells(y).innertext

    For x = 0 To cellrangex
        For y = 0 To cellrangey
            cellrange = cellrange2
        Next y
    Next x
End With


End Sub
```

Comment: It's possible to do, and you are headed in the right direction. Is there a specific problem with this code that you are struggling with. Does that `htm.getElementById("comments")` work? Is there an element with that ID in that page's html?

Comment: I actually wasn't too sure what element ID I would be able to use to pull just the comments, so I used it as a placeholder.

Comment: @JNevill As for the problem with this code, it is just the fact that I've gotten stuck and don't know where the problem is. Whenever I try running it, it returns nothing. I've tried tweaking it for a while now and nothing seems to work.

Comment: As an aside, it may be worth taking this opportunity as an exercise to learn Python, as [PRAW](https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) is excellent, there are several good Excel-writing Python libraries, and the entire process will be much simpler than trying to do this directly in Excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll really need to analyze the contents of the web page you are scraping with a decent HTML editor. I would suggest navigating to the page in question in chrome and using F12 to open it's developer tool. In the "Elements" tab you can quickly see which HTML is producing which part of the page (open both the page and the developer tools next to each other).

You'll notice as you head into the comments that the text of each comment is inside a `<p>` tag and each `<p>` tag is inside a `<div>`. We are looking for patterns, so this is a good start.

You'll also notice that each one of those `<div>` tags has a `class` of `md`. 
So... Lets load all of the pages `<div>` tags into an object and then look for the ones that have a `className` that contains `"md"`:

Sub getRedditData()

```
Dim x As Long, y As Long
Dim htm As Object

Set htm = CreateObject("htmlFile")

With CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")
    .Open "GET", "https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/4p7qsx/what_are_the_most_common_modern_day_scams/", False
    .send
    htm.body.innerhtml = .responsetext
End With

Set Divelements = htm.getElementsByTagName("div")

For Each DivElement In Divelements
    If InStr(1, DivElement.ClassName, "md") Then
        'print contents to the Immediate window for debugging View>>Immediate Window to insure it's up in your VBE
        Debug.Print DivElement.InnerText
    End If
Next
```

End Sub

With that you'll see all of the comments stuck in the Immediate window (go to View>>Immediate Window) so you can see this debug output.

---

After skipping around the nodes it looks like you can navigate up a couple of elements and back down the tree to get the username:

```
Sub getRedditData()

    Dim x As Long, y As Long
    Dim htm As Object

    Set htm = CreateObject("htmlFile")

    With CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")
        .Open "GET", "https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/4p7qsx/what_are_the_most_common_modern_day_scams/", False
        .send
        htm.body.innerhtml = .responsetext
    End With

    Set Divelements = htm.getElementsByTagName("div")


    On Error Resume Next

    For Each divElement In Divelements
        If InStr(1, divElement.className, "md") And Not InStr(1, divElement.className, "md-container") Then
            Set commentEntry = divElement.ParentNode.ParentNode.ParentNode

            'Print the name and the comment
            Debug.Print commentEntry.FirstChild.FirstChild.NextSibling.InnerText & ":", divElement.InnerText

        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

To print this out to the sheet just point to a cell instead of the `debug.print` immediate window. Something like:

```
Sub getRedditData()

    Dim x As Long, y As Long
    Dim htm As Object
    Dim ws As Worksheet, wsCell As Integer

    'set the worksheet to print to and the first row to start printing.
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
    wsCell = 1

    Set htm = CreateObject("htmlFile")

    With CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")
        .Open "GET", "https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/4p7qsx/what_are_the_most_common_modern_day_scams/", False
        .send
        htm.body.innerhtml = .responsetext
    End With

    Set Divelements = htm.getElementsByTagName("div")


    On Error Resume Next

    For Each divElement In Divelements
        If InStr(1, divElement.className, "md") And Not InStr(1, divElement.className, "md-container") Then
            Set commentEntry = divElement.ParentNode.ParentNode.ParentNode

            'Print the name and the comment to ws sheet columns 1 and 2
            ws.Cells(wsCell, 1).Value = commentEntry.FirstChild.FirstChild.NextSibling.InnerText
            ws.Cells(wsCell, 2).Value = divElement.InnerText

            'iterate to the next row
            wsCell = wsCell + 1

        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the explanation as well. Is there a way I can now move the data from the Immediate Window into the spreadsheet cells?

Comment: No problem. I've added how to get the username (you'll see how to navigate through the nodes/elements in the structure with that) and then how to print out to the sheet instead of the debug window. Just keep poking around the nodes until you find what you want. Scraping is more of an art than a science.